# How to Sort the elements as per sequence given in XSD xshema file with XSLT 2: perform-sort

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using SaxonHE jars for XSLT 2.0 processors to change the sequence of the elements to the required sequence by XSD. But not getting the desired output.
My xml file is:

```
<param xsi:type="Bank">  
     <bankData name="ABC"/>  
     <branchAddress id="ABCB1">NY</branchAddress>  
     <legalAddress id="ABCL1">UK</legalAddress>  
</param>
```

As per XSD , the correct sequence for child elements of param tag  is bankData,legalAddress,branchAddress.
Tag param can contain any type of data. So the sequence should be changed if attribute type is "Bank"

I am using this XSL code to change the sequence:

```
<xsl:variable name="bankElementSeq" as="element()*">  
    <bankData/><legalAddress/><branchAddress/>  
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:template match="param/*">  
   <xsl:if test="param/@xsi:type='Bank'">  
       <xsl:perform-sort select="param/*">  
           <xsl:sort select="index-of($bankElementSeq//node-name(.), node-name(.))"/>  
       </xsl:perform-sort>  
   </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>
```

Required output is:

```
<param xsi:type="Bank">  
   <bankData name="ABC"/>  
   <legalAddress id="ABCL1">UK</legalAddress>  
   <branchAddress id="ABCB1">NY</branchAddress>  
</param>
```

But I'm getting output as:

```
<param xsi:type="Bank">  
</param>
```

The child elements are not written.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: There is nothing in this question particular to Saxon so I have removed this tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this code in more detail:

```
<xsl:template match="param/*">  
   <xsl:if test="param/@xsi:type='Bank'">  
       <xsl:perform-sort select="param/*">  
           <xsl:sort select="index-of($bankElementSeq//node-name(.), node-name(.))"/>  
       </xsl:perform-sort>  
   </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>
```

Firstly, this template is applied to each child of param *in turn*. It affects how the selected element is processed, it does not affect when the selected elements are processed. To rearrange the children of "param", you need logic in the template for the "param" element, not the template for its children.

Secondly, within the template you have a relative path expression param/@xsi:type. This is evaluated relative to the context node, which is a child of "param". So you are looking for a grandchild of param that is itself named param. Your example XML doesn't have such a grandchild. You repeat this mistake in the path expression of the xsl:perform-sort/@select.

So you could actually achieve what you want like this:

```
<xsl:template match="param[@xsi:type='Bank']">  
   <xsl:perform-sort select="*">  
      <xsl:sort select="index-of($bankElementSeq/node-name(.), node-name(.))"/>  
   </xsl:perform-sort>    
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Now its working with perform-sort but only child elements got written. param tag was removed from output xml.

Comment: Ok got it. added copy code from Marcus code to copy param element as well.<xsl:copy> <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

Comment: I got one more issue want to replace one common attribute value of any tag. Old Attribute value is system=Legacy which need to change to system=AdvMig How to do this in xslt 2.0?

Comment: @user2025527: The last comment of yours is a new question in itself not related to the one here. However, there should already be many answers to this on StackOverflow. By the way: I don't think the answer will depend on the XSLT version.

Answer (score 0):

See @MichaelKay's solution for a good explanation why your current approach does not work.

I would like to suggest a slighty different approach. It does not try to sort the entries but simply uses your auxiliary variable to *iterate* over the child tags in `param`. This should be functionally equivalent now but may some have some advantage in other setups in which you only want to output a *subset* of tags. You would simply only include the desired tags in the auxialiary variable and leave all others out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="bankElementSeq" as="element()*">  
    <bankData/><legalAddress/><branchAddress/>  
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- the following pattern restricts the match to exactly the type of param you want to modify -->
  <xsl:template match="param[@xsi:type='Bank']">  

    <xsl:copy>     
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="param" select="."/>

      <!-- iterate over the elements in the sorting order -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$bankElementSeq">        
        <!-- and copy the found found by 'local-name' -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$param/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]"/>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Its working for child elements of param tag. But attributes are not getting copied in new xml. The param element is <param>..</param> without its attributes.

Comment: @user2025527: Thank you for the hint. See my updated XSLT above.